# How to create a virtual point cloud (VPC) with S3 URLs to read COPC files in QGIS 3.32?

Tags: qgis, amazon-web-services, laz, s3, copc

I have been converting LAS files (pdrf 6) to COPC using QGIS 3.32. It then reads well in QGIS but doesn't once uploaded on AWS S3. The bucket is not public, so I have tried to input AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID use the authentification pannel found from the Data Source Manager, and also the environment variable of QGIS via Options> System.

[image]

[image]

The network error return is:

***WARNING    Error transferring https://xxxxxxxx.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/copc_test/test.copc.laz - server replied: Forbidden***

Do COPCs need to be generated differently if hosted online? Is it an AWS config problem?

Loading a COG from the same private AWS S3 location does work ok. It seem to be a PDAL issue.
Any idea what can be done to handle the authentification and generate a VPC from S3 URLs?

Comment: Just an idea: use rclone to mount the bucket in a local point. Let rclone manage the authentication and all network stuff, and qgis read from local. But it is not really an answer about how to read copc from s3 in qgis.